# MVC Controller and Web Flow Controller - Request handling priorities

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm working with integration Spring Web Flow into Spring MVC web application.

I mapped Spring `DispatcherServlet` to `*.html` like below.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have registered simple flow (`/WEB-INF/flows/simple/simple-flow.xml`, `/WEB-INF/flows/simple/simple.jsp`) that gets `simple` id according to configuration.

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

I mapped `/simple.html` (`/WEB-INF/pages/simple.jsp`) to my MVC Controller.

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

    @RequestMapping("/simple.html")
    public String simpleHandler(Model model) {
        return "simple";                    
    }
}
```

When i request `simple.html`, the `SimpleController` get that request, but when i remove mapping to that controller, `simple.html` leads to `simple` flow. I see that MVC controller have higher priority and get request before it reach flow controller. Of which is the result? How it works in that situation ? Can i change request handling order/priorities of ordinary MVC controllers and Web Flow controller ?

Comment: Have you seen http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch10s03.html?

Comment: Yes, I have the same configuration. So... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done it using `order` property. It is set to `0` by default and MVC controllers handling request before flow controller. I set order to `-1` and now flow controller handle request before it reach my MVC controller. Is it good solution ?

```
<!-- Handle request after MVC controllers -->       
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>

<!-- Handle request BEFORE MVC controllers -->      
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
    <property name="order" value="-1"/>
</bean>
```